# function call with ASYNC/AWAIT

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm sure this issue is from my lack of async/await knowledge. However, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Endgoal is for the addSupplier() process to wait on getSuppliers() function to finish processing until it continues.

Background info:
This is inside of a much larger Electron application utilizing HTML, JS, and Postgres. This snippet of code is processing a request from HTML form to insert a supplier into the table, then refresh the HTML table which is located on the same page. HTML code is not shown but I can include if needed.

Current code - not split into separate functions - works as desired:

```
function addSupplier(){
  const connString = getConnData();
  const client = new Pool(connString)
  client.connectionTimeoutMillis = 4000;

  var supplierID = document.getElementById("dbSupplierID").value;
  var supplierName = document.getElementById("dbSupplierName").value;
  var supplierUnit = document.getElementById("dbSupplierUnit").value;

  const supplier_insert_query = {
    text: "INSERT INTO suppliers(supplier_id, company, unit)VALUES('"+ supplierID +"', '"+ supplierName +"', '"+ supplierUnit +"')",
  }

  const supplier_select_query = {
    text: "SELECT supplier_id AS id, company, unit FROM suppliers",
    rowMode: 'array',
  }

  // Connect to client, catch any error. 
  client.connect()
  .then(() => console.log("Connected Successfuly"))
  .catch(e => console.log("Error Connecting"))
  .then(() => client.query(supplier_insert_query))
  .catch((error) => alert(error))
  .then( () => { // After inserting new author, run author query and refresh table. 
    client.query(supplier_select_query)
    .then(results => {
      // Create the static header for the table
      var table = ""; table_head = ""
      for (i=0; i<results.fields.length; i++) { if (i==3) {continue}
        table_head += '<th>' + results.fields[i].name + '</th>'
      }

      // Create the body of the table
      for (j=0; j<results.rows.length; j++) { //j: rows, k: columns
        results.rows[-1] = []
        if (results.rows[j][0] == results.rows[j-1][0]) {continue}
        table += '<tr>'
        for (k=0; k<results.fields.length; k++) { if (k==3) {continue} // Skip creating the last column of this query. This data is only used to add information to the first column.
          if (k==0) { // When you've reached a session_id cell, write the names of the tests in this session in that cell
            var x=0; x = j; var tests = ''
            while (results.rows.length > x && results.rows[x][0] == results.rows[j][0]) {
             tests += '<br>' + (results.rows[x][3]==null ? '':results.rows[x][3]); x++
            }
          }
          table += `<td>${results.rows[j][k]}` + (k==0 ? `${tests}`:``) + '</td>'
        }
        table += '</tr>'
      }

      // Grab the constructed HTML strings and write them to the document to create the table there
      document.getElementById('supplier_table_head').innerHTML = ""
      document.getElementById('supplier_table').innerHTML = ""

      document.getElementById('supplier_table_head').innerHTML += table_head
      document.getElementById('supplier_table').innerHTML += table
    }).catch(e => console.error("ERROR in supplier table query\n",e.stack))
  })
    
  // Clearing input fields.
  document.getElementById('dbSupplierID').value = ""
  document.getElementById('dbSupplierName').value = ""
  document.getElementById('dbSupplierUnit').value = ""

  // Preventing app refresh
  event.preventDefault()
  
  .finally(() => client.end())
}
```

EDIT: I made the async changes and it seems to call the function correctly but the function does not process. This is what I have now. If I throw in an alert, it processes the alert 'TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function' and then kicks out and refreshes the entire application.

```
// Function to add a supplier to the DB
async function addSupplier(){
  const connString = getConnData();
  const client = new Pool(connString)
  client.connectionTimeoutMillis = 4000;

  var supplierID = document.getElementById("dbSupplierID").value;
  var supplierName = document.getElementById("dbSupplierName").value;
  var supplierUnit = document.getElementById("dbSupplierUnit").value;

  const supplier_insert_query = {
    text: "INSERT INTO suppliers(supplier_id, company, unit)VALUES('"+ supplierID +"', '"+ supplierName +"', '"+ supplierUnit +"')",
  }

  // Connect to client, catch any error. 
  client.connect()
  .then(() => console.log("Connected Successfuly")) // Connection is good
  .catch(e => console.log("Error Connecting"))      // CATCH - Connect error
  .then(() => client.query(supplier_insert_query))  // Run supplier insertion query
  .catch((error) => alert(error))                   // CATCH - error in insertion query
  .then(async () => {
    // wait for getSuppliers function to execute
    await getSuppliers();
  }) 
  .then(() => {
    // Clearing input fields.
    document.getElementById('dbSupplierID').value = ""
    document.getElementById('dbSupplierName').value = ""
    document.getElementById('dbSupplierUnit').value = ""

    // Preventing app refresh
    event.preventDefault()
  })
  .catch(e => console.error("ERROR in supplier table query\n",e.stack)) //Catch any error from getSuppliers
  .finally(() => client.end())                      // Close the connection
}

async function getSuppliers(){
  let promise = new Promise()
  // Query to pull all Suppliers info from database
  const supplier_select_query = {
    text: "SELECT supplier_id AS id, company, unit FROM suppliers",
    rowMode: 'array',
  }

  // Query the database and pull the results into the HTML table
  client.query(supplier_select_query)
    .then(results => {
      // Create the static header for the table
      var table = ""; table_head = ""
      for (i=0; i<results.fields.length; i++) { if (i==3) {continue}
        table_head += '<th>' + results.fields[i].name + '</th>'
      }

      // Create the body of the table
      for (j=0; j<results.rows.length; j++) { //j: rows, k: columns
        results.rows[-1] = []
        if (results.rows[j][0] == results.rows[j-1][0]) {continue}
        table += '<tr>'
        for (k=0; k<results.fields.length; k++) { if (k==3) {continue} // Skip creating the last column of this query. This data is only used to add information to the first column.
          if (k==0) { // When you've reached a session_id cell, write the names of the tests in this session in that cell
            var x=0; x = j; var tests = ''
            while (results.rows.length > x && results.rows[x][0] == results.rows[j][0]) {
             tests += '<br>' + (results.rows[x][3]==null ? '':results.rows[x][3]); x++
            }
          }
          table += `<td>${results.rows[j][k]}` + (k==0 ? `${tests}`:``) + '</td>'
        }
        table += '</tr>'
      }

      // Grab the constructed HTML strings and write them to the document to create the table there
      document.getElementById('supplier_table_head').innerHTML = ""
      document.getElementById('supplier_table').innerHTML = ""

      document.getElementById('supplier_table_head').innerHTML += table_head
      document.getElementById('supplier_table').innerHTML += table
    })
  .finally(() => {return promise.resolve()})
}
```

Comment: How are you supposed to call `await` in a method that is not `async`?

Comment: Shouldn't run at all, you can't use `await` inside a function that isn't `async`. Does it not show any error messages? And why not just do the `getSuppliers()` call in a separate `.then()` like everything else? Seems strange having everything in a `.then()` chain except for one function call.

Comment: @GuyIncognito in the first code example, the getSuppliers code is in a .then(). In the second code example, both functions are labeled as Async, or did I create them incorrectly?     and no, no errors in VS Code

Comment: This function: `.then(() => { await getSuppliers()` is not labeled async.

Comment: @GuyIncognito okay, should I put the async inside the 'then' housing like this -  .then( async() => { await getSuppliers() } ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix function declaration with `async` key word to use `await` key word inside of it.

```js
client.connect()
  .then(() => console.log("Connected Successfuly")) // Connection is good
  .catch(e => console.log("Error Connecting"))      // CATCH - Connect error
  .then(() => client.query(supplier_insert_query))  // Run supplier insertion query
  .catch((error) => alert(error))                   // CATCH - error in insertion query
  .then(async () => {
    // wait for getSuppliers function to execute
    await getSuppliers()

    // Clearing input fields.
    document.getElementById('dbSupplierID').value = ""
    document.getElementById('dbSupplierName').value = ""
    document.getElementById('dbSupplierUnit').value = ""

    // Preventing app refresh
    event.preventDefault()
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword waits for a promise to be resolved before running code after it ([await in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)). You haven't made `getSuppliers` create or resolve a promise, so await isn't waiting for anything here. I'm not very familiar with creating and resolving promises myself, but something like `promise = new Promise()` at the beginning of `getSuppliers` and `return promise.resolve()` at the end should work properly.

EDIT: It also seems like you're missing an `async` before the arrow function with `await getSuppliers()`, that could be causing issues as well. I might have jumped the gun on assuming promises were the issue, as the `await` keyword does try to convert anything that isn't a promise to a resolved one, but I'm not familiar with how consistently this works the way it should.

Comment: I took your advice, but I still have an issue. check out my edit in the top.